# Failed to build module 'Razorpay' from its module interface

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, razorpay

Build failed with the following errors:

```
failed to build module 'Razorpay' from its module interface; the compiler that produced it, 'Apple Swift version 5.2.4 (swiftlang-1103.0.32.9 clang-1103.0.32.53)', may have used features that aren't supported by this compiler, 'Apple Swift version 5.3 (swiftlang-1200.0.29.2 clang-1200.0.30.1)'
```

and

```
<unknown>:0: error: unable to load standard library for target 'arm64-apple-ios10.0'
```

**Razorpay pod Version :**

> pod 'razorpay-pod', '1.1.7'

**Xcode Version :**

> Version 12.0.1 (12A7300)

I was working on our code which was earlier build on xcode 10 and razorpay pod was 1.1.1. With xcode 12 it was failing so I updated rayzorpay-pod 1.1.7

followed instruction is given in the [documentation](https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/ios-integration/standard/#cocoapod)
changed `var razorpay: Razorpay!` to `var razorpay: RazorpayCheckout!`
and `initWithKey` function as well

Comment: not a single suggestion/reply?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The razor pay pod is not compatible with Xcode 12.

The razor pay pod `v1.1.9` is in pre-release(See below image) which is Xcode 12 complied version.

[image]

What you can do is just update the razor pay pod version to `1.1.7` to `1.1.9` and give it a try.

Or you can use razor pay pod `v1.1.8`(stable release) in lower than Xcode 12 version and when `v1.1.9` is available you can move it Xcode 12.

You can do the following to use `v1.1.9`...

- Comment the razor pay pod from pod file.

  ```
  #pod 'razorpay-pod', '1.1.7'
  ```
- Run `pod install` command from terminal
- Now razor pay pod is removed from your project.
- Now add pod which is Xcode 12 compatible.

  pod 'razorpay-pod', '1.1.9'
- Run `pod install` command
- Build your project. If it succeeds you can move on, if not, then you have to downgrade Xcode version until `v1.1.9` is fully available.

Comment: 1.1.9 is not found. I guess I'll have to downgrade or have to wait till it releases.

Comment: Yes, you need to downgrade Xcode I order  to use the razor pay. Once they releases stable version of `v1.1.9` you can start using Xcode 12.:)